# Passing NON null-terminated strings to unmanaged code

Tags: .net, string, interop, pinvoke, marshalling

Consider the following struct to be sent over TCP to an unmanaged dll

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct FooMessage
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 42)]
    public string foo;

    //More fields...
}
```

Using the following function (credit to [Cheeso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929540/c-send-structure-objects-through-socket/1929763#1929763)):

```
public byte[] RawSerialize( T item )
{
    int rawSize = Marshal.SizeOf( typeof(T) );
    IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( rawSize );
    Marshal.StructureToPtr( item, buffer, false );
    byte[] rawData = new byte[ rawSize ];
    Marshal.Copy( buffer, rawData, 0, rawSize );
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal( buffer );
    return rawData;
}
```

Problem: The marshaller assumes foo is a null terminated string, whereas the unmanaged dll does not - and actually uses the last char (which always comes out null from the marshaller).

Any ideas ?

**Clarification**: I can't just change the SizeConst to 43, because I need to maintain the total size of the message, as well as the position of the next fields in the struct (according to an existing ICD)

Comment: Using a char[] is indeed the way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no other answer has been posted, here is the [workaround](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/250805-sharing-structure-containing-char-array-using-memory-mapped-file) I've found

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct FooMessage
{
    // use this for non-null-terminated strings
    // use default encoder to convert to and from string
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=42)]
    public char[] foo;

    //More fields...
}
```

Also a [similar](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/02/interop-multidimensional-arrays-of.html) solution by TCP expert Stephen Cleary

Comment: It seems really strange to me that there is no Marshalling attribute that can help marshaling non null-terminated strings...

Comment: We ended up hiding (private) the char[] field and defining a public property on the struct with getter and setter that converts the char[] to string and vice-versa. It also applies Trim and Pad as necessary.

Comment: `public string Foo {
  get => new string(this.foo);
  set => this.foo = value.ToCharArray();
}`

Add a property like this to make things less painful.

Answer (score 2):

You could use StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit ...) and tag each field with [FieldOffset(*n*)]. This will allow you to increase the SizeConst value to 43, *and still* mark the next field as starting at offset 42. The marshaller will marshal the 42 character string and ignore the 43rd byte appending a null-terminator instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have two, and only two, choices:

1. make the dll understand about NUL-terminated strings; or
2. send a character count with the message and make the dll understand that count.

One or the other, take your pick.

-- b

Comment: The dll is out of my control. I actually have found a workaround, see OP. just wondering if there is a better way, though I doubt it.