# Using C++ code in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have c++ dll with class in wich I want to send string from C# code, surly I can't use string because of CLR, i'll stried to change string into char in c++ dll, and send byte from c#(because c++ char=byte in c#) but c# don't understand c++ array I can send 1 byte and it will be ok, but not array, please help!
dll Code:

```
public ref class Coding
    {
    public:
        void HillCoding(char filePath[])
        {

            ...
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you share with us the C++ function's signature?

Comment: At runtime with `P/Invoke`, the CLR will convert `string` into `char *` I believe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing NON null-terminated strings to unmanaged code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435163/passing-non-null-terminated-strings-to-unmanaged-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code of calling C++ dll function from C#:

```
    sbyte[] A_SB_array = new sbyte[0];
    ArrayConvCtoSB(ref A_SB_array, ar_param.ToCharArray());
    fixed (sbyte* SB_array = A_SB_array)
        return CPSFEW.getDataLength(SB_array);
```

It's not the "very good code" but it illustrate what you need.

PS: Here is ArrayConvCtoSB. I do not like it, it's just for understanding.

```
    static private void ArrayConvCtoSB(ref sbyte[] to_sbyte, char[] from_char)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < from_char.Length; i++)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref to_sbyte, to_sbyte.Length + 1);
            to_sbyte[i] = (sbyte)from_char[i];
        }
    }
```

PPS: "fixed" is strongly required for forceing garbage collector not to clear the SB_array memory: otherwise it can. :)

Comment: One more addition. Here is the declaration of getDataLength C++ function: "size_t getDataLength(const char *param) {...}"

Answer (score 1):

Try this first, because CLR converts `string` to `char *`, no?:

```
callThisCPlusPlusMethod(myString)
```

If that doesn't work, Use

```
char[] sendArray = myString.ToCharArray();
callThisCPlusPlusMethod(sendArray);
```

Or, if needed in different encoding:

```
byte[] sendArray = Encoding.TheEncodingINeed.GetBytes(myString);
callThisCPlusPlusMethod(sendArray);
```

Note:
I tend to like ambiguous names :)

Comment: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'std.basic_string<char,std.char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >*'

Comment: If your signature is the same as the one above, then _theoretically_ that should work, I have no idea what the problem would be... did you try all the other methods I posted?